# Xamarin Android: Get installed app list with icons

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I create Xamarin Android app in VS2017.
How get installed app list with icons? and run program from this list.

Comment: What exactly have you tried yet, to get that list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get installed apps list(in non activity class)

```
var apps = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MatchAll);
```

Get app name:

```
apps[0].LoadLabel(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager);
```

Get package name:

```
apps[0].PackageName;
```

Get app icon:

```
apps[0].LoadIcon(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager);
```

Run app from list:

```
Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(apps[0].PackageName);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I know this post is a bit old, but I was wondering about getting the app icon. You have the same command listed as to get the app name `LoadLabel`. I was wondering if this is a mistake? If not, how is it processed? I am trying to work with `LoadIcon` but not having much luck.

Comment: Yes that mistake